# Disable Windows 7’s “Open File - Security Warning” dialog for exe on local drive?

Tags: windows-7, security, eclipse

I am trying to run Eclipse java-galileo-SR2-win32 when I get `open-file-security-warning`. The files are just extracted from a zip file and put into a directory "`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\LocalLow\eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32\eclipse`".

The Internet Explorer settings for adding network drives to the intranet zone do not work on local drives. Also there is no option to 'unblock' the file in the file properties.

What other option is there to turn off this annoying prompt? Or even better be able to select which files are considered safe to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to put the directory where it belongs such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32\eclipse` this the removes the open file security warning dialog. `c:\Users\UserName\AppData\LocalLow` directory must have similar security as the intranet zone.

Comment: If anyone knows why the LocalLow folder is restricted like this can you please tell us why?

Comment: That is its sole purpose. Trusted data goes in c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local, untrusted data in ..\LocalLow.

My understanding is that, if a pre-Vista program attempts to write to the users application directory (ie what used to be
c:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data) then this is magically remapped to either Local, LocalLow or the Roaming subfolder inside c:\Users\UserName\AppData depending on which mode the program is running in. So if program is running in low security mode , then it can only write to LocalLow which is also low security.

Answer (score 10):

In the start menu enter `gpedit.msc`. Then go to:

`User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Attachment Manager`

and Add `*.exe` to the "Inclusion list for moderate risk file types" setting.

Comment: I want to be able to select which exe are allowed to run, rather than allow all of them.

Comment: @Menuta: Just a long shot, but you try adding "filename.exe" instead? It appears to work for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, hadn't thought of that, obvious really. I have already moved the files to program files anyway which has bypassed the error.

Comment: Adding `eclipse.exe` works great!  +1

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that one of the other files (maybe a dll) is blocked?

[Streams from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) is a handy command line utility which can be used to display NTFS streams on all files in a directory and sub-directories. It can also be used to remove all the streams (assuming that they are all just Zone.Identifiers)

Comment: I tried that no luck.

Comment: This is THE solution.
    streams -s -d "C:\Program Files\Eclipse"