# Windows 7: Open File - Security Warning box appears for every app on the desktop

Tags: windows-7, security, security-warning

Whenever I double-click to open an executable on the desktop (.exe, .bat, etc.), or a shortcut on the desktop that points to an executable, the "Security Warning" pops up and asks me "Are you really sure you want to open that? Stuff from the Internet is dangerous!"

I don't usually mind this warning and don't want to [disable it globally](https://superuser.com/questions/134245/disable-windows-7s-open-file-security-warning-dialog-for-exe-on-local-drive), but now I'm getting it for any executable on the desktop, even ones that I didn't download from the Web and don't have the Mark of the Web alternate data stream. (That is, [`streams -d *`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440) shouldn't and doesn't help.)

This started fairly recently, but I can't really point to anything I did that triggered it. It only occurs in one user account on the machine; the other account doesn't have this problem. Running System Restore didn't help.

How can I fix the problem and make the pop-up warning appear only when it's supposed to?

Comment: This sounds like a virus its self... did you download the 'Security Warning' software or something?

Comment: Maybe, but I hope I'm not that stupid :P Besides, I have a decent real antivirus app (Microsoft Forefront).

Comment: Does this come with all Windows 7 Distros? Because when I installed this one, I didn't have to turn such a feature off.. I've seen the 'This publisher cannot be verified one', but not this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I snatched the answer from Microsoft Technet site (which somehow resembles very much with stack overflow sites, hmmmm....):

```
C:\>ICACLS "C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\Desktop" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)M
```

Comment: Hm, forcing the [mandatory integrity level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Integrity_Control) of the desktop folder to Medium seems to have worked! Strange, though, nobody ever mucks with that setting, so it should usually be Medium by default.